# making a custom marker using google map api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API V3. i want to use a custom marker instead of that red marker. Earlier the code was

```
   var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // display map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    if(display_marker) {
        // create a map marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
        });
    }
```

but for the custom marker, i changed the code to

```
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // display map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


        // create a map marker
        var image = 'imgs/pin.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: image
        });
```

but yet this is not working.

Comment: Would help a bit if you told us what happens since it doesn't work. I suppose a javascript error, or simply no marker on the screen? If it's a javascript error you have written something wrong, and if no marker shows I would assume your path to the pictures is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image path is likely incorrect but,

You could also eliminate `var image` and just define the icon under `var marker` depending on your situation.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: 'imgs/pin.png',
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay.

Perhaps the image path is off.

Try putting the `pin.png` in the same folder as the map and then changing the

`var image = 'imgs/pin.png';`

to

`var image = 'pin.png';`

If it works, then you need to revise the path, probably to something like

`var image = '/imgs/pin.png';`

or

`var image = '../imgs/pin.png';`